# paypal checkout button: payment popup never completes

Tags: javascript, paypal, checkout

I am implementing the paypal checkout.

I have the following javascript code
paypal.Button.render({

```
                            env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',
                            client: {
                                sandbox:    'sandbox_id',
                                production: 'producton_id'
                            },
                            commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button
                            payment: function(data, actions) {
                                return actions.payment.create({

                                    transactions: [
                                        {
                                            amount: { total: '<%-Number(totalprice).toFixed(2)%>', currency: 'ILS' }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                });
                            },
                            // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
                            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                                // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                                });
                            }

                        }, '#paypal-button');
```

[image: paypal popup]

The popup (above image) appears when I click the paypal button and I can fill in credit card details etc as in the image. Its in sandbox so am using test card number. When I click the pay now button it says processing and returns back to the same form over and over again. I see now info in console or in my callbacks

Please help

I see

```
{"id":"PAY-1C642132RR146080LLEVTNSA","intent":"sale","state":"created","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"320.00","currency":"ILS"},"related_resources":[]}],"create_time":"2017-05-28T20:44:56Z","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1C642132RR146080LLEVTNSA","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-9D899580GW067815A","rel":"approval_url","method":"REDIRECT"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1C642132RR146080LLEVTNSA/execute","rel":"execute","method":"POST"}]}
```

What is weird is I seem to get same experience on the interactive demo (ie the popup remains) and beneath there is the site with the overlay.

Here is what I see on my site
[image]

I am also actually thinking the payment has occurred looking at the payment  in network traffic

{"id":"PAY-7RE93639XV754372PLEW4GKY","intent":"sale","state":"created","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"1045.00","currency":"ILS"},"related_resources":[]}],"create_time":"2017-05-30T19:08:27Z","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-7RE93639XV754372PLEW4GKY","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-8NH468700E7063747","rel":"approval_url","method":"REDIRECT"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-7RE93639XV754372PLEW4GKY/execute","rel":"execute","method":"POST"}]}

but I need to know how to have the popup window close and for it to return to my code in the onAuthorize

i.w was expecting to see my alert

onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

```
                                // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {

                                    alert('Payment Complete!');

                                });
                            }
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your network tab? There should be a request to `/execute`, can you copy and paste the response for that?

Comment: I added what I see re execute. This appears as the popup appears but nothing more in network when I click pay now but it returns to the same form

Comment: I have found that I see the exact same behaviour with the paypal demo https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is surprising. Your alert is being displayed *behind* the Paypal popup dialog window. This is what happened to me when I did an alert. Mine was in a very similar situation

```
    onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
      return actions.payment.get().then(function () {
        ..
        if (problem condition) { alert('message'); location.reload(); }
```

The paypal dialog wait-spinner spun forever. When manually closing their dialog window, the alert appeared from behind.

Instead, include a hidden div in your main screen, with the acknowledgement text; and in the "return actions.payment.execute().then(function () {", change it to display:block. You can include more information from the payment, e.g. paymentDetails.payer.payer_info.first_name and last_name or shipping.recipient_name